# Javascript doesn't work with changed value

Tags: javascript, input, onblur

I got this input:

```
<input name='num2' type='number' id=num2 onblur="checkValue(this)">
        <script>
    function checkValue(input) {
    console.log(input.value);
  if (input.value > 20) {
     return input.value = 20;
  } else if (input.value < 0){
     return input.value = 0;
  } else if (input.value == '' || isNaN(input.value)) {
     return input.value = 0;
  } else {
     return input.value;
  }
}
$("#num1, #num2").focusout(function() {
    $("#answer").html('');
    var num1 = $("#num1").val();
    var num2 = $("#num2").val();
    var answer = num1 * num2;
    $("#answer").html(answer);
});
        </script>
```

the problem is that when I write the number whitch is higher than 20 so the input value change, but javascript still continue to count with what ever the number I write in, for exampe 100000. But I want that javascript count with the onblur changed value. Please show me at least if I going the right way or should I use some other script.

Comment: makes no sense to have the return statements

Comment: so trigger the event after you adjust the number.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code below you will see that the `focusout` handler is called **before** the `onblur` handler.

```js
function checkValue(input) {
  console.log('blur', input.value);
  if (input.value > 20) {
     input.value = 20;
  }
  else if (input.value < 0){
     input.value = 0;
  }
  else if (input.value == '' || isNaN(input.value)) {
     input.value = 0;
  }
  else {
     input.value;
  }

}
$("#num1, #num2").focusout(
  function() {
    $("#answer").html('');
    var num1 = $("#num1").val();
    var num2 = $("#num2").val();
    var answer = num1 * num2;
    console.log('focusout', num1, num2, answer);
    $("#answer").html(answer);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='num1' type='number' id=num1>
<input name='num2' type='number' id=num2 onblur="checkValue(this)">
<div id="answer"></div>
```

So you are not limiting the number in `num2` until after you calculate your `answer`.

Maybe you should move your logic to limit your `num2` within the `onblur` handler.

**UPDATE**

The example below will set the limits on both input fields before calculating the totals.

> If neither of these examples are what you want then please explain your desired result so we can help.

```js
function checkValue(input) {
  console.log('blur', input.value);
  if (input.value > 20) {
     input.value = 20;
  }
  else if (input.value < 0){
     input.value = 0;
  }
  else if (input.value == '' || isNaN(input.value)) {
     input.value = 0;
  }
  else {
     input.value;
  }

}
$("#num1, #num2").focusout(
  function() {
    $("#answer").html('');
    var $num1 = $("#num1");
    var $num2 = $("#num2");
    checkValue($num1[0]);
    checkValue($num2[0]);
    var num1 = $num1.val();
    var num2 = $num2.val();
    var answer = num1 * num2;
    console.log('focusout', num1, num2, answer);
    $("#answer").html(answer);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='num1' type='number' id=num1 onblur="checkValue(this)">
<input name='num2' type='number' id=num2 onblur="checkValue(this)">
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but your method **doesnt work for me**

Comment: I can't help if I don't know what is failing.

Answer (score 0):

solution was very simple.. :) sorry for this topic.. true is that I had to add more value with if,, but if someone have a better result direct for blur pleas post it

```
 <input name="num1" type='number' id=num1 value="<?php echo round($final5, 2); ?>" disabled><br />
 <input name='num2' type='number' id=num2 onblur="checkValue(this)">
        <script>
    function checkValue(input) {
    console.log(input.value);
  if (input.value > 10) {
     return input.value = 10;
  } else if (input.value < 0.09){
     return input.value = 0.1;
  }  else {
     return input.value;
  }

}

$("#num1, #num2").focusout(function() {
    $("#answer").html('');
    var num1 = $("#num1").val();
    var num2 = $("#num2").val();
    if (num2 > 10) {
        num2 = 10;
    } else if (num2 < 0.1 ) {
        num2 = 0.1;
    } else {
        num2;
    }
    var answer = num1 * num2;
    $("#answer").html(answer);
});
        </script>
```